# Java -- Must return type boolean (But I am returning true or false)

Tags: java, boolean, return

```
public class CodingBat {
public static void main(String[] args){
    CodingBat object = new CodingBat();
    System.out.print(object.parrotTrouble(true,20));
}
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
    if(talking == false){
        return false;
        }
        else if(hour > 7 || hour >20){
            return true;
            }
    }
```

}

I am confused, why I am getting an error where the public method parrotTrouble is underlined saying it must return a boolean, which I currently have?

Comment: There is a 3rd possibility, the compiler won't know if one of the other conditions will ALWAYS be met, so it requires you to provide a 3rd/fail safe condition

Comment: The test `hour > 20` will never be checked, since `hour > 7` is always true when hour > 20.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler says you need to return some value since your method return type is `boolean`.

You have `returned false in If condition`, and `return true in else if condition`.

**you need to return something outside of if/else if as well.**

something as below, as per comments from @Andreas, code can be reduced to below

**Original as per OP**

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
        if (talking == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (hour > 7 || hour > 20) {
            return true;
        }
        return booleanValue; // can be true/false as per your logic
    }
```

**Edit**

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
        return (talking && (hour > 7 || hour > 20));
    }
```

> As pointed by @Codebender, wither use `if else condition`, then no
>   need to return boolean value at the last, but if you are using `if -
>   else if` you have to return boolean value at the last. As compiler is
>   also not sure that it will go in one of the conditions surely.

Comment: There's actually no `else` condition, only `else if`... And that's the problem actually... If he had an `else`, it would 've run properly...

Comment: @MichaelCowie yes code is fine, you just need to initialize variable `answer` with some default value.  `boolean answer = false;`

Comment: Of course, the obvious fallback is `return false`, since the parrot doesn't cause trouble during the day (assuming the check is corrected to say `hour < 7`), so it can be condensed to `return (talking && (hour < 7 || hour > 20));`. --- Also, you should change code back to use `boolean`, not `Boolean`, as the parameter.

Comment: @Andreas correctly pointed, made and edit, `Boolean` i was experimenting something, so typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
    boolean answer = false;
    if(talking == false){
        answer = false;
        }
        else if(hour < 7 || hour >20){
            answer = true;
            }
    return answer;
    }
```

Thank you for your help, I changed my code to this and it worked correctly and answered the question <3